# redirect causes Page not found error

Tags: python, django

redirect causes Page not found error.I wrote in html

```
<form method="POST" action="/app/save/">
    <p>name：<input id="name" type="text" name="NAME"></p>
    <p>email：<input id="email" type="text" name="email"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="SEND"></p>
</form>
```

in views.py

```
def top(request):
    return render(request, 'top.html')

def save(request):
    save_form = SaveForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == "POST" and save_form.is_valid():
        save= save_form.save(commit=False)
        name = request.POST.get("name", "")
        email = request.POST.get("email", "")

        save.name = name
        save.email = email

        save.save()
    return redirect("app:top")
```

in urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('top', views.top,name='top'),
    path('save', views.save,name='save'),
]
```

I really cannot understand why such a error happens.I wrote save's url in urls.py so I think urls&views' connection is OK.Furthermore,i think the way of writing redirect is not wrong.How should I fix this?What is wrong in my codes?

Comment: have you checked the path of top.html and the directories you've listed in the settings.py file to look for templates?

Comment: @AshishAcharya Yes,I already checked it.top method move normally, so I think path is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the wrong argument to `redirect()` - you have to pass [an actual URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect), not a URL name. Change it to:

```
from django.urls import reverse

return redirect(reverse("app:top"))
```

Currently you are being redirected to `/app:top` which is of course a non-existent URL.